# Efficiently transforming rows to columns in Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'd like to convert the following `DataFrame`:

```
   idx  key  val
0    1  foo    2
1    1  bar    4
2    1  qux    8
3    2  foo   10
4    2  bar   12
5    2  qux   14
```

To:

```
     key_foo  key_bar  key_qux
idx                           
1          4        2        8
2         12       10       14
```

That is: each `key` becomes a colummn `key_<key>`, with the `idx` column becoming the new index by which the key-value pairs are grouped into rows.

How should I do that?  The `DataFrame` is very large, so I'd like to perform that transformation efficiently.

Comment: Try.... `df.pivot('idx','key','val').add_prefix('key_').rename_axis(None, axis=1)`

Comment: @ScottBoston worked perfectly, thanks!